# "Call stack" for callbacks in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, stack-trace, control-flow

I'm used to thinking in Java and I'm trying to get my head around node.js.  My program needs to log information when things go wrong, and I find I'm having to put in a lot of boilerplate code in my node.js program to get what I'd get for free in Java.

My question boils down to:

- is there an easier/non-boilerplate way to get stack-like information in a chain of callbacks? and/or
- am I guilty of failing to grasp node.js properly, and trying to force asynchronous node.js to be more like synchronous Java?

## Java Example

Here's a noddy Java program which tries (and fails) to connect to a Mongo database:
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;

```
import com.mongodb.Mongo;

public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        final Mongo mongo = a();
    }

    private static Mongo a() throws UnknownHostException {
        return b();
    }

    private static Mongo b() throws UnknownHostException {
        return c();
    }

    private static Mongo c() throws UnknownHostException {
        return new Mongo("non-existent host");
    }

}
```

...which gives this helpful stack output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: non-existent host
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(Unknown Source)
at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.updateInetAddress(ServerAddress.java:204)
at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.<init>(ServerAddress.java:73)
at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.<init>(ServerAddress.java:46)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:138)
at Test.c(Test.java:20)
at Test.b(Test.java:16)
at Test.a(Test.java:12)
at Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

(In particular, the last 4 lines show me "what was happening" in my own code at the time the Mongo error occurred.)

## Node.js Example

Here's my attempt to re-write my program in node.js:

```
a(function (err, mongo) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Something went wrong in main");
        console.log(err);
    }
});

function a(callback) {
    b(function (err, mongo) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Something went wrong in a()");
            return callback(err);
        }

        return callback(null, mongo);
    });
}

function b(callback) {
    c(function (err, mongo) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Something went wrong in b()");
            return callback(err);
        }

        return callback(null, mongo);
    });
}

function c(callback) {
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    return MongoClient.connect('mongodb://non-existent host/', function (err, mongo) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Something went wrong in c()");
            return callback(err);
        }

        return callback(null, mongo);
    });
}
```

...which gives this output:

```
Something went wrong in c()
Something went wrong in b()
Something went wrong in a()
Something went wrong in main
[Error: failed to connect to [non-existent host:27017]]
```

But to get this output, I have to put in lots of boilerplate code throughout my program, which is going to be a pain to police as my program gets larger and I have a whole development team.

Can I get this stack-like output another way?  Is it un-node-like to expect this kind of output?

Comment: Promises might be what you're looking for; they convey the typical success and failure of (asynchronous) processes in a consistent manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promises are exactly what you are looking for (bring back the stack features to async code)

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
// enable long stack traces, bluebird specific
Promise.longStackTraces();
// promisify mongodb so that it returns promises, also bluebird specific
Promise.promisifyAll(mongodb);
// raise stack limit, feature of v8/node.js
Error.stackTraceLimit = 100;


function c() {
    var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
    return MongoClient.connectAsync('mongodb://non-existent host/')
}

function b() {
    return c()
}

function a() {
    return b()
}

a().then(function(connection) {

});
```

Gives:

```
Possibly unhandled Error: failed to connect to [non-existent host:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/petka/bluebird/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:546:74)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/petka/bluebird/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:150:15)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/petka/bluebird/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:533:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:830:16
From previous event:
    at Function.connectAsync (eval at makeNodePromisifiedEval (/home/petka/bluebird/js/main/promisify.js:199:12), <anonymous>:7:21)
    at c (/home/petka/bluebird/throwaway.js:10:28)
    at b (/home/petka/bluebird/throwaway.js:14:16)
    at a (/home/petka/bluebird/throwaway.js:18:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/petka/bluebird/throwaway.js:21:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

You can use catch (named so because it works like a real catch statement) in one place:

```
 a().catch(function(e) {
      //handle e
 });
```

Also bluebird specific features added to catch:

Predicated catches are also supported since it's just a method:

```
 a().catch(SyntaxError, function(e) {

 });
```

Predicate can be an error constructor or a predicate function

```
 // define a predicate for IO errors
 function IOError(e) {
     return "code" in Object(e);  
 }
```

Comment: I think this "from previous event" feature of your library is what you should advertise here. OP is complaining about manually having to write out `log("something went wrong at …")` everywhere, isn't he?

Comment: @Bergi agree, I'll remove the log version

Comment: You might also want to highlight that this is not an inherent property of promises, but an implementation feature of some libraries.

Comment: @Bergi oh yea, I annotated bluebird specific stuff

Answer (score 0):

How about using stack trace from the error:

```
function trace(err)
{
    console.log(err);
    var stack = new Error().stack;
    console.log(stack);
}


a(function (err, mongo) {
    if (err)
    trace(err)
});

function a(callback) {
    b(function (err, mongo) {
        if (err)
        return callback(err);
        else
        return callback(null, mongo);
    });
}

function b(callback) {
    c(function (err, mongo) {
        if (err)
        return callback(err);
        else
        return callback(null, mongo);
    });
}

function c(callback) {
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    return MongoClient.connect('mongodb://nohost/', function (err, mongo) {
        if (err)
        return callback(err);
        else
        return callback(null, mongo);
    });
}
```

Output

```
[Error: failed to connect to [non-existent host:27017]]
Error
    at trace (/myfolder/a.js:4:14)
    at /myfolder/a.js:11:2
    at /myfolder/a.js:17:10
    at /myfolder/a.js:26:10
    at /myfolder/a.js:36:10
    at /myfolder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:406:11
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:339:11)
```

Now it is not as verbose as the one you got in Java, it does not give function names, but it helps in identifying the chain of execution.

Comment: …unless the methods which you want in your stack trace (`a`, `b`, `c`) use higher-order functions to generate the callbacks. In that case you'd only get the line numbers of the generator functions.

Answer (score 0):

longjohn seems to be very popular now a days for getting long stack traces in node.js

http://blog.nodejitsu.com/npmawesome-full-stack-traces-with-longjohn/

http://www.mattinsler.com/post/26396305882/announcing-longjohn-long-stack-traces-for-node-js

Here is a list of other such modules that might be helpful in identifying what you need

https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/stack

Example Code:

```
var longjohn = require('longjohn')
var stackTrace = require('stack-trace');
longjohn.empty_frame = 'ASYNC CALLBACKS :';
a();

function a() {

    b();
};

function b() {
    c();
}

function c() {

    setTimeout(function() {

        throw new Error("My Custom Error");

    }, 1000);

}

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {

    //in JSON format with the help of stack-trace module;
    console.error(stackTrace.parse(err));

    //in plain text format
    console.error(err.stack.trim());

    process.exit(1);

});
```

Output in plain text format with longjohn:

```
Error: My Custom Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/nav/Documents/workspace/stack_trace/hello-world-server.njs:19:9)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)
ASYNC CALLBACKS :
    at c (/Users/nav/Documents/workspace/stack_trace/hello-world-server.njs:17:2)
    at b (/Users/nav/Documents/workspace/stack_trace/hello-world-server.njs:12:2)
    at a (/Users/nav/Documents/workspace/stack_trace/hello-world-server.njs:8:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nav/Documents/workspace/stack_trace/hello-world-server.njs:4:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Output in plain text format without longjohn:

```
Error: My Custom Error
    at null._onTimeout (/Users/nav/Documents/workspace/stack_trace/hello-world-server.njs:19:9)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```